# Getting the values of method parameters inside expression trees

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

I'm messing around with expression trees, but I'm little stuck.

I have this expression:

```
Expression<Func<IX, int>> expr = i => i.GetAll(1, b, method());
```

Where :

```
int b = 2;

public static int method()
{
    return 3;
}

public interface IX
{
    int GetAll(int a, int b, int c);
}
```

Now I want to get name of the method and values of parameters for this method. Name of the method is easy, but parameter values are harder part. I know I can parse them myself, but I would need to handle all cases (`ConstantExpression`, `MemberExpression`, `MethodCallExpression` and maybe more I'm not aware of). So I was thinking if there was "general" way to get their values. eg 1, 2, 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the arguments of the `MethodCallExpression` in question
 and create  compiled `Func<object>`s from them (boxing value-types if necessary), which can then be evaluated.

E.g.:

```
var args = from arg in ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Arguments
           let argAsObj = Expression.Convert(arg, typeof(object))
           select Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(argAsObj, null)
                            .Compile()();
```

This will obviously blow up if the expression's body is not a method-call expression or if any of the arguments to the method cannot be evaluated as is (e.g. if they depend on the argument to the expression).

Obviously, you can do a better job if you know the types of the arguments to the method beforehand. For your specific example, this should work:

```
var args = from arg in ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Arguments               
           select Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(arg, null)
                            .Compile()();
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted. And conversion to object is good idea too, because I dont know what types might this method's parameters be.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just get all the parameters and then compile and execute them?   I don't see how it would be possible to get all the values without executing if they can be method calls.