# Getting the current index in a for loop in a Lambda expression

Tags: c#, razor, lambda

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the values of method parameters inside expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181269/getting-the-values-of-method-parameters-inside-expression-trees)

Given the following code:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FormerAddresses.Count; i++)
{
    <li>@Html.Editable(m => m.FormerAddresses[i].Street)</li>
}
```

How do I get the value of 'i' in my 'Editable' extension? I know I can get the value of this expression by doing the following:

```
var value = ((LambdaExpression)expression).Compile().DynamicInvoke(MyViewModel);
```

But how do I get the value of the 'i'? It should be possible since compiling the expression returns me the correct result, but I cannot find a way to find out how this is done. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found it! Thanks StackOverflow. Was using the wrong search terms I guess.

Link to answer:
[Getting the values of method parameters inside expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181269/getting-the-values-of-method-parameters-inside-expression-trees)